# Need to find a way to programmatically delete undeleteable empty folders

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, windows-xp

I've got a large folder on an offsite backup machine that gets populated with files by rsync (through deltacopy) every night (running windows xp) from the main work site. I've discovered some annoying folders that cannot be opened, or deleted, or even checked for file sizes. I get the such and such a folder is not accessible, access is denied message when I try to click on it in windows explorer. According to the windows explorer tooltip they are also "empty" and the properties of these folders say 0 bytes and 0 files.

I currently have a C# program that goes through every folder and file and tries to copy the whole backup directory to a dated backup-backup directory, which is how i discovered this problem in the first place. The regular System.IO library seems helpless against these blasted folders. Exceptions are thrown when I even try to access the folder path.

Does anyone have any clue how I could, say, on an access denied exception in my existing copy code, force the delete of these folders so rysnc can recreate the directory again and get the whole thing synced again?

Comment: Can you attempt to access these folders with elevated permissions?

Comment: not sure what you mean, I'm running as the administrator. How do I get higher permissions than that?

Comment: On Windows XP there is no distinction between administrator and elevated rights.  Starting with Vista you can have an administrator account but still have processes running with a restricted token.

Comment: I do realize you want a programmatic solution, but this isn't so much a C# question as a "how do I get my OS to do this?" question.  Therefore, you might want to look into *how* the various locked file deletion tools work.  Here's one product that includes a list of many others, purely for research: http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/

Comment: If i can't solve this I shall indeed move to linux. It's a little more complicated I'm just a contractor and their full time IT guy prefers to have everything in windows.

Comment: Steven- unlocker managed to remove the folders. Not sure I have the wherewithal to figure out how it was done, though! Probably some nasty low level filesystem work.

Comment: This is not a .NET question at all. Are you able to access these folders using Windows Explorer? I bet you get the exact same problem. The problem is that the OS uses the same message for "you don't have permissions" as for "someone has this locked, so you can't have it". You'll need to use some utility like Handle from SysInternals  to find out why the folder is locked. Maybe then you can write a program to overcome that specific issue.

Comment: @IsaacB - i think some of the folks here, are on crack tonite.

Comment: @John Saunders - you are funny.

Comment: @softwareGeek: I wasn't trying to be funny. What was the problem with what I wrote? What struck you as "funny"?

Comment: @John Saunders - your answer is no different than my solution. What are you suggesting new? i find it amusing.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: did you suggest he write a program? I did. I suggested he find out what kind of thing is locking the files. Perhaps there's some process that leaves the folder locked. He could then write a program to see if that process is still running and kill it if necessary. I'm suggesting he first use the tools to find out what the problem is, then write a program to address the specific problem he finds with the tools. You suggested just using the tools.

Comment: Just to be clear there is no process locking the folder according to 'unlocker'. It's probably a broken file system.

Comment: @John Saunders - you are totally wrong.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: I've occasionally disagreed with John on judgement calls, but I can't remember seeing him actually wrong.

Comment: @IssacB: I doubt it's a "broken file system".  If you really want to solve this, you need to use the tools we've been talking about to gain some insight into the actual cause.  Only then can you consider doing something about it.

Comment: It might be a 'broken file system'. Chkdsk found 'orphaned files' with related names.

Sorry for the foul language but I don't understand how NTFS works.

Comment: Obvious question: Have you been powering down the machine while there's disk I/O?

Comment: I haven't, but I'm not the only one with access to the machine. The writes occur early in the morning which makes it unlikely the IT guy did it. There have been some crashes of the OS though. Maybe this was an effect of one of those. At least now I can manually fix these with unlocker.

Comment: @Dan: Apparently, you were right all along, in that IssacB says it was a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was that SYSTEM owned these files. I set deltacopy to run as administrator so that administrator would own the files deltacopy makes.

I guess windows is doing its job. The permissions are airtight. But if this happens again someday where I'd have to grab ownership from some other user to the current user (who has administrator permissions) how would I do that in code?

A question for another day I suppose. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I think of when I see this is time to do a checkdisk. From the sounds of it, it feels more like a file system problem than something solvable the way you want to go about it.

Comment: chkdsk did find some relevant irregularities, in fact. But it did not fix the problem for me. <sigh> I guess the move to linux is unavoidable.

Comment: @IssacB: You can move to Linux if you wish, but do consider the fact that, somehow, people manage to work with Windows and NTFS without being blocked by the problems you're encountering.

Comment: I think you are right Joel.

My solution to this will be to use my copy program to identify broken files and directories and email them to me. Then I'll use unlocker to delete them manually. This probably happened because I'm using a very unreliable POS computer for this job, and it decided to crash in the middle of a write or something.

Thanks for recommending unlocker again steven, that is a pretty useful program!

Comment: Sorry, this was not the problem. I have copied the same folder over again through rsync and I have the same problems. I can access the files fine on the main fileserver but not on the backup. The mystery continues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try the awesome [**"Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)" from Microsoft (formerly SysInternals).

Although it's for the processes in the windows filesystem, you could search for your folder in the explorer window & it will tell you who is locking it.

Once you release the process, your program would be able to delete the folder.

If that doesn't work, see if you can specify additional parameters to bruteforce the delete in your program.

Comment: He wants a programmatic method of dealing with it, therefore, it needs to be done via code automatically, not a manual process using a third party app.

Comment: Yes, only if he can kill the process that's keeping the folder, will his program be able to delete it. what's wrong with that approach?

Comment: Tried this, I searched for the folder in the process explorer search with no results. Besides, assuming this keeps happening once in awhile I need to have a procedure to deal with it automatically, hence the plea for C# help.

Comment: He needs to be able to do it without human intervention. Your method requires a user to perform a task with a system utility. Hardly appropriate for an end-user application

Comment: -1. As others have said, he said "programmatic". This requires him to run the application; he wants to automate it.

Comment: Jeez, give me a break, will ya?

Comment: @SoftwareGeek regarding downvotes. They are nothing personal, they are a method of showing the helpfulness of an answer. Since the answer does not address the question asked, the -1. If this was a question on Super, I would have given a +1

Comment: Wow, can't believe this got down voted. Perhaps there is a process keeping the folders locked. If the same program is consistently locking these folders you could surely programmaticaly kill it but until he finds out if this is the case....

Seems like a reasonable suggestion to me.

Comment: @jwsample - I coudn't believe it either.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek et. al. If you hover over the down arrow, you'll see it say "This answer is not useful". Since the OP asked for a programmatic method, and you didn't give one, that deserves a downvote (and you got mine).

Comment: Quick! Someone downvote the chkdsk suggestion as that also might help narrow down the problem! Strange place this.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: be as honest about it as I am, and I'll be pleased to receive your downvotes.

Comment: @jwsample - tell me about it. some folks are hungry to downvote, i guess they feel like god & get a kick out of it. Look at John S for ex: He downvotes me & then comments almost exactly as my answer. Strange indeed. This is too much, i have had enough of it for one night.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: first of all, my comment should be a hint that your answer would have been better as a comment, since it doesn't answer the question. Also, my comment is different: I say "find out what's wrong, then maybe you can write a program to fix it". I meant, find out once, then the program would be able to fix it many times.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the filenames are either bad or contain characters that are invalid in Win32. Did you try to delete the directories with `rd /r`? Did you do a `dir /x` on them and try to delete the files/directories using their short names?

I would say that you first have to figure out why you can't delete the folders. Once you figure that out, you can write a program to fix it.

OK, so now that you know it's a permissions problem, the first step is to take ownership of the files (so you can set the permissions), then change the permissions so that you can delete the files.

Here's code to take ownership of a file:

```
WindowsIdentity currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); 

FileSecurity acl = File.GetAccessControl(filename); 
acl.SetOwner(currentUser.User); 

File.SetAccessControl(filename, security);
```

Comment: access denied. access denied.

Comment: What does `cacls` say? Is it possible the directory is owned by another use and you don't have permissions for it?

Comment: Okay, I was led on a wild goose chase. I don't know why my thinking was so unclear today. Anyhow, it was a permissions issue. System owned those files. chkdsk led me astray by finding orphaned files in that directory. Grrr. I will look into how to change the permissions on folders in C# if that is possible.

Comment: Changing permissions is easy in .NET, but you have to actually understand ACE's, DACL's, SDDL and the rest.  Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx

Comment: I ended up making deltacopy server run on the administrator account. Now there aren't anymore permissions problem. Thanks for everyone's help!